# Using the VB function split I get Compile error: "Can't Assign to array".

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to use the split() function to split out a name based on spaces in the given name string in Microsoft Access. When attempting to compile the code I've written below I get a Compile error: "Can't Assign to array".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Public Function cleanName(position As Integer, inName As String) As String

Dim nameArray() As String
Dim outName As Variant

nameArray = Split(inName, " ")

Select Case position
    Case 1 'Titles
        outName = nameArray(0)
    Case 2 'First Name
        outName = nameArray(1)
    Case 3 'Middle Name
        outName = nameArray(2)
    Case 4 'Last Name
        outName = nameArray(3)
    Case 5 'Suffix
        outName = nameArray(4)
    Case Else
End Select

cleanName = outName

End Function
```

Comment: Try using "Set nameArray = Split(inName, " ") or nameArray() = Split(inName, " ") (been a while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code this way:

```
   nameArray() = Split(inname, " ")
```

Comment: I still get the same error with nameArray()= Split(inName, " ")

Comment: That's bizarre. I was about to post a snip to show how this assignment should work just fine. I wonder if you've inadvertently got multiple libraries with SPLIT available and you're unintentionally referencing one that doesn't return a string array...

Comment: From the VB IDE, go to the "Object Browser," (usually just hit F2) and just under the dropdown that says <All Libraries>, type "Split" and see if more than one function appears. You want the one from VBA.Strings.

Comment: That's a possibility but I've striped it down to the only two references being "Visual Basic for Applications" and "Microsoft Access 15.0 Library Object Library" and still get the error.

Comment: Ignore that last comment. I did as you said and it turns out a function that a co-worker had written was also called Split and it was attempting to use that split. I commented it out and it worked fine. I'm going to go have a word with my co-worker now.

Comment: AWESOME!! Glad I was able to help! Three cheers for the object browser :)

Comment: @DavidW could you please add the explanation regarding multiple versions of `Split` to your actual answer as well? Might be helpful for future readers without having to read the comments.